# Question about the second derivative test

Tags: calculus

In my calculus textbook it says

The Second Derivative Test:
Suppose that f" is continuous near c.
(a) If f'(c)=0 and f"(c)<0, then f has a local minimum at c
(b) If f'(c)=0 and f"(c)>0, then f has a local maximum at c

I’m curious why we need the assumption “suppose that f" is continuous near c”.

Is there any example explaining it?

Thanks

Comment: You are right, that assumption is not needed. One needs only that $f''(c)$ exists, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Second-derivative_test_(single_variable)

Comment: if $g'(x)<0$ then $g$ is decreasing at a neighborhood of $x$ - This claim is true and is enough to infer the "second derivative test", so continuity is not needed. (Be sure you understand the geometrical intuition)

Comment: I think either you or the author of the textbook also got the sign wrong. If $f''(x_0)>0$, $x_0$ is a local minimum, not a local maximum, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks all! Have a good day :)